# ¿Como abrir una pestaña en un monitor secundario con javascript en chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

Hola llevo varios días buscando como abrir una pestaña en mi monitor secundario con javascript en chorme, el problema es que aún no encuentro nada al parecer google chrome lo restringe pero tengo la esperanza de que alguien sepa como.

Encontré este código pero ya no funciona, al menos Chrome lo probé en Firefox y ahí si funciona, lo anexo por si a alguien le sirve

```
 function OpenSecondScreen() {
    var w = 1800;
    var h = 300;
    var left = 1900;
    var top = (window.screen.height / 2) - (h / 2);

    var win = window.open("yourpage", "_blank", 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width=' + w + ', height=' + h);
    win.moveTo(left, top);
}
```

Si alguien me pudiera ayudar se los agradecería mucho.